# how to make a picture fit in a static control vc++ win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi

can you tell me how to make a picture fit in a static control, i mean like if you create a static control for viewing pictures and if the picture quality or size of picture is bigger than control then it re size the static control with the size of picture. i could create the control and set the picture to it alright. but i don't know how to make it fit on control. this is how i create control and set picture to it.

Code:

```
HWND static_con(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInst){
    HWND Static_Pic;

    Profile_Pic = CreateWindow("STATIC", NULL, SS_BITMAP|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP, 5,5,33,33, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "camera1.jpg", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if(hBmp == NULL){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error while loading image", "Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    SendMessage(Static_Pic, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp);
    return 0;
}
```

and then i call the function in WM_CREATE handler which creates it successfully and now i don't know how to make it fit on control, i really appreciate if you could tell me how to make the picture fit on control.

Comment: You need to use an extra style for the window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [SS_REALSIZEIMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773.aspx) might be an option, although it is not clear to me, whether this can load image formats other than ICO. It is also not clear to me, whether you can load a file from disk, or embedded resources only. Since resizing the Static control usually implies a sizing operation of the parent window as well, I would suggest manually adjusting both sizes ([SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx)).

Comment: I presume profile_pic is a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SS_REALSIZECONTROL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/desktop/Controls/static-control-styles)
From Microsoft's documentation.

```
SS_REALSIZECONTROL - Adjusts the bitmap to fit the size of the static control.
```

You can also manually scale the image. Get the size of the control where image is to go by using GetWindowRect(), then by using StretchBlt() scale the image so that its dimensions match that of the source, then do STM_SETIMAGE.